# How is QueryList populated by Angular?

Tags: angular

I am looking at the definition of QueryList class. It contains private property `_results`, but no method to populate this property. How does angular populates objects of `QueryList` class?

declaration:

```
export declare class QueryList<T> {
    private _dirty;
    private _results;
    private _emitter;
    readonly changes: Observable<any>;
    readonly length: number;
    readonly first: T;
    readonly last: T;
    /**
     * See
     * [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
     */
    map<U>(fn: (item: T, index: number, array: T[]) => U): U[];
    /**
     * See
     * [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
     */
    filter(fn: (item: T, index: number, array: T[]) => boolean): T[];
    /**
     * See
     * [Array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)
     */
    find(fn: (item: T, index: number, array: T[]) => boolean): T | undefined;
    /**
     * See
     * [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
     */
    reduce<U>(fn: (prevValue: U, curValue: T, curIndex: number, array: T[]) => U, init: U): U;
    /**
     * See
     * [Array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
     */
    forEach(fn: (item: T, index: number, array: T[]) => void): void;
    /**
     * See
     * [Array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)
     */
    some(fn: (value: T, index: number, array: T[]) => boolean): boolean;
    toArray(): T[];
    toString(): string;
    reset(res: Array<T | any[]>): void;
    notifyOnChanges(): void;
    /** internal */
    setDirty(): void;
    /** internal */
    readonly dirty: boolean;
    /** internal */
    destroy(): void;
}
```

Similarly, there I am confused about the declarations of map, filter... for map, there is only 1 line:

```
 map<U>(fn: (item: T, index: number, array: T[]) => U): U[]
```

sure, map accepts a function, but that is just the signature. How does it know what to do with argument function?

I am clearly missing some core concepts here of how Angular works...